# Использование буферов OpenGL в OpenCL - ошибка "InvalidContext"

Tags: c#, opengl, opencl

Мне требуется использовать буферы `OpenGL` в `OpenCL`.
при использовании метода `clCreateFromGLBuffer` выдаёт ошибку `InvalidContext`.
я где то прочитал что нужно добавить свойства при создании контекста `OpenCl`

```
ContextProperty[] contextProperties = new[]
{
     new ContextProperty(ContextProperties.CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, Win32.wglGetCurrentContext()),
     new ContextProperty(ContextProperties.CL_WGL_HDC_KHR,Win32.GetDC(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)),
     new ContextProperty(ContextProperties.CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,_platform.handle), 
}
```

я добавил но появилась ошибка при создании контекста

> System.AccessViolationException: Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.

Также, констант `CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR` и `CL_WGL_HDC_KHR` не было в библиотеке которую я скачал в NuGet значения констант я нашёл на [на этом сайте](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/extensions/khr/cl_khr_gl_sharing.txt)

Как это исправить?

полный код

```
Glfw.Init();
window = Glfw.CreateWindow(500, 500, "");
Glfw.MakeContextCurrent(window);
OpenGL gl = new OpenGL();

Platform[] platforms = Cl.GetPlatformIDs(out errorCode);
foreach (Platform platform in platforms)
{
     Device[] devices = Cl.GetDeviceIDs(platform, DeviceType.Gpu, out errorCode);

     if (devices.Length == 0)
     {
          continue;
     }

     _platform = platform;
     _device = devices[0];
     break;
}
ContextProperty[] contextProperties = new[]
{
     new ContextProperty(ContextProperties.CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, Win32.wglGetCurrentContext()),
            new ContextProperty(ContextProperties.CL_WGL_HDC_KHR,Win32.GetDC(window.Ptr)),
            new ContextProperty(ContextProperties.CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,_platform.handle), 

};
_context = Cl.CreateContext(contextProperties, 1, new Device[] {_device}, null, IntPtr.Zero, out errorCode);
```

Comment: А ваш OpenGL контекст связана HDC Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle? Вот пару статей как подружить OpenGL&OpenCL https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-and-opengl-interoperability-tutorial, https://github.com/9prady9/CLGLInterop

Comment: вообщем я нашёл проблему на момент создания массива не была инициализирована платформа но теперь другая ошибка при создании контекста `InvalidValue`

Comment: Приведите по больше кода, т.к. вы только указали свойства. У вас OpenGL и OpenCL контексты в одном потоке живут?

Comment: @Unick да в одном

Comment: Надеюсь ваш девайс поддерживает cl_khr_gl_sharing: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_gl_sharing.html

Comment: Насколько я понимаю один из параметров у clCreateContext это callback для вывода ошибок, может быть его передать и вы получите больше информации об ошибки. А если создавать без OpenGL контекста, то работа?

Comment: @Unick как я уже писал он возвращает ошибку `InvalidValue` . без openGl всё работает.

Comment: Можно поробовать wglGetCurrentDC() для получения DC или glfwGetWGLContext(window).

Comment: @Unick  не помогло

Comment: А попробуйте убрать последную , (запятну) из массива contextProperties. Может он думает что там на 1 элемент больше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вообщем ему не хватало одного элемента в массиве.

```
ContextProperty[] contextProperties = new[]
{
    new ContextProperty(ContextProperties.CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, wglGetCurrentContext()),
    new ContextProperty(ContextProperties.CL_WGL_HDC_KHR,wglGetCurrentDC()),
    new ContextProperty(ContextProperties.CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,_platform.handle),
    new ContextProperty(0,IntPtr.Zero), 

};
```

вот так всё работает.